# How change global elasticsearch index creation setting?

Tags: elasticsearch

OS: #1 SMP Debian 4.19.152-1 (2020-10-18)

Install elastic by this tutorial https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html:

```
{
  "name" : "web",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "HSeOQvkHRey2P_JN2Nv-GA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "51e9d6f22758d0374a0f3f5c6e8f3a7997850f96",
    "build_date" : "2020-11-09T21:30:33.964949Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

How globally change some index creation options https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html?
Such as `index.max_ngram_diff` as example?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [index update settings API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html):

```
PUT your-index/_settings
{
  "index.max_ngram_diff": 2
}
```

If you want this setting to be applied on index that are going to be created in the future, you can create an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-template.html) that will be applied to the matching future indexes:

```
PUT /_index_template/template_1
{
  "index_patterns" : ["my-index-*"],
  "priority" : 1,
  "template": {
    "settings" : {
      "index.max_ngram_diff" : 2
    }
  }
}
```

After that, every time that you create a new index whose name matches `my-index-*`, that new index will get the settings set in the template.

Comment: It's only for existed indexes?
How to set this option for indexes that will be only created, for example with ruby?

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to use [Index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-template.html) for this. You can preconfigure template with settings you need, and use on index creation.